# Perl one-liner to split a line into multiple lines iteratively

Tags: regex, perl, iteration, newline, one-liner

I have a tricky problem and I'm wondering if there's a clever regex solution. I have input data that consists of two columns, but the first column needs to be split into multiple lines with the second column intact. For example, a file called test:

```
cat_;_dog_;_rat animal
chair_;_desk    object
```

The output needs to look like this:

```
cat animal
dog animal
rat animal
chair    object
desk    object
```

There are an arbitrary number of *;* separators on each line. There is probably a way to do this in a one-liner, which I prefer since I'm piping the data in and out. I tried this:

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+)_;_(\w+)\t(.+)/$1\t$3\n$2\t$3/g' test
```

The first column has words `(\w+)` delimited by `_;_`, then a tab, and then the second column. But this only consumes one iteration of the data:

```
cat     animal
dog_;_rat       animal
chair   object
desk    object
```

I tried the following too just in case the `/g` global tag wasn't getting it right:

```
perl -pe 's/(\w+)(_;_(\w+))+\t(.+)/$1\t$4\n$3\t$4/g' test
```

It still only goes one round. Who's got some ideas?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, your retagging edits are [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425287)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perl -lane 'print "$_ $F[1]" for split /_;_/, $F[0];'
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line and runs the code for each line;
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output;
- `-a` splits each input line on whitespace into the `@F` array;
- [split](http://p3rl.org/split) splits the first column on `_;_`, and for each value, it prints it (`$_`) followed by the second column.